# How to do dynamic TCP ports dispatch in distributed simuliation

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, distributed-computing

I have a main programme which start 4(actually it can be any number) child process. They will wait until all 4 is there and continue to simulation.

In order to achieve that, a fixed port is used, like "1004"

But problems comes when there are multi users of this programme. By only using 1004, there can be only one user per time.

So I updated the main programme which checks between "1004-10010" and dispatch the port. The code is like:

```
find available ports
close the ports (I see I must close the ports so that child process can run)
start sub process given the ports

code: 
          boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(tcp::v4(), port_number);
          boost::system::error_code ec;

          _acceptor.open( ep.protocol());
          _acceptor.bind( ep, ec);

          if (ec)
          {
            port_number++; ec.clear(); _acceptor.close();
          } else
          {
            _acceptor.listen();
            port_number = _acceptor.local_endpoint(ec).port();
            port_found = true;
          }

          ...............
          _acceptor.close();
          ---races here-----
          start child process
```

But as many people mentioned before, I have races. So I still face some error from time to time.

Anyone have any idea how I can improve it?

1. Lots of you mentioned my child process shall find an available ports and notify my main programme.While that's a good way but really hard to achieve in my case.
2. Is there any way to reserve a port to let chiled process use without closing it?

Comment: Is it the parent, or the children that are listening on the port ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on what I understand of your description, that is: you launch a program A who launch 4 other process which communicate with A on port 1004, you would like to be able to launch another A before first A is finished. Right ?

1. First instance of your program A detect that it is the first and setup as a 'socket server' (creating socket and waiting for connection).
2. Second instance of A detect that he is not the first, and so 'socket connect' through private protocol to the first instance in order to launch the child process.

Tips:

1. When creatin the socket, if you give 0 as port number you will get back an available port number.  You can give this port number on command line of the child process. This way you have a dedicated socket to communicate with the childs.
2. In order to detect if threre is another instance of your program, you can deduce that from failing to create a socket on dedicated port (1004 in your case).